# Pass sub-state from sub-module to the main module in angular.js with angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I design my SPA like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['submodule0', 'submodule1']);
```

Main module:

```
$stateProvider.state("sub0index", {
            url: "/sub0",
            // pass states defined in submodule0, is that possible?
        }).state("sub1index", {
            url: "/sub1",
            // pass states defined in submodule1
        })
```

And here are some states defined in submodule0

```
$stateProvider.state("index", {
    url: "/index",
    templateUrl: "template/index.html"
}).state("info", {
    url: "/info",
    templateUrl: "template/info.html"
})
```

So is that possible that I pass sub-state from sub-module to the main module? I ask this because now I define all my state in my main module, I think it may be more elegant to define the state of one submodule in the submodule itself.

And another question is: I'm not sure my module design is reasonable or not, is my submodules not necessary? Or just keep my whole app logic to one module? Thanks.

====Edited====

And here is the problem I've met.

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ui.router', 'app.sub']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: "/a",
        views: {
            "general": {
                templateUrl: "/template.html"
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            data: 'GetDataService'
        }
    });
}
```

The service `GetDataService` is defined in my submodule `app.sub`, and here is the service:

```
angular.module('app.sub',['ui.router'])
    .service('GetDataService', ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {

        console.log($stateParams);
        return null; // return null just for demo
    }]);
```

The output of `console.log($stateParams)` is an empty object. But if use the service which is defined in its own module, the current state can be get correctly. So whats the issue?

===Edit===

Thanks for the example, it works fine if give a `factory` to `data` directly. But how about I give it a string?

I check the document of ui-router, and there is something about map object in `resolve`:

> factory - {string|function}: If string then it is alias for service.

So if I use the code like this:

```
resolve: {
        data: "GetDataService"
}
```

And the definition of `GetDataService`:

```
.service('GetDataService', ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {

    console.log($stateParams);
    return null;
}])
```

But output of `console.log($stateParams)` is always an empty object.

Do I have some misunderstanding about the [api document](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)?

===Edit again===

If I use code like this:

```
resolve: {
        // data: "GetDataService"
        data: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {

            console.log($stateParams);
            return null;
        }]  
    }
```

I can get the params object.

Comment: Is there anything not working for you? Because the answer is: you can split your stuff into many modules. You can even have parents in one and children in another. It really dependes on your needs. But by design UI-Router supports any approach. *NOTE: My experience - I would use one module for states... maybe with states lazy loading... until today, I did not find any benefit when having many modules*

Comment: @RadimKöhler Thanks, and I edited my question and show the issue I've met, it actually can be fixed in another way, but I want to know about why cause this issue?

Comment: I would say, that when we want to use **Service** which should do some stuff related to our current state, we should pass current state info as params... I will append answer with a draft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that modules should not stop us... we can split the app into many if needed.

But I would suggest: Services should be independent on `$state.current`. We should pass to them function parameters as needed, but these should be resolved outside of the Service body.

Bette would be to show it in action - there is [one working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKZSPLoHu31liAHekrDQ?p=preview)

This is the service:

angular.module('app.sub',['ui.router'])
    .service('DataService', ['$state', function($state) {

```
    return {
      get: function(stateName, params){
        console.log(stateName);
        console.log(params);
        return stateName;
      }
    }
}]);
```

And here is some adjsuted state def:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: "/a/{param1}",
        views: {
            "general": {
                templateUrl: "tpl.html"
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            data: ['DataService','$stateParams'
            , function(DataService,$stateParams, $state){
                return DataService.get('index', $stateParams)
            }], 
        },
    });
}])
```

Hope it helps a bit. The [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKZSPLoHu31liAHekrDQ?p=preview)

Because this approach is ready to test service without any dependency on some "external" $state.current. We can just pass dummy, testing params

Comment: Thanks, but I still have some problem, I post it above.

Comment: The answer is - use string if you do not depend on current state, on parameters. It is then very convenient method how to pass function name... But if you need set params - and you do need that, because you have to pass some info about the context - you should not use string. Use a function with defined params... Take it as my suggestion.. wanted to show how.

Comment: The most important message I am trying to tell you: 1) we talk about the `resolve: {}`, almost the resolve phase of the **state** 2) you want to read the current state in this phase ... while we are not there yet! So - We do resolve stuff to get to state... and make it current. This is my message.. Hope it helps a bit

Comment: Your messages are very helpful. But last question I posted is about `$stateParams`, with string, I always get an empty object, but with function, I can get the params obejct, is there something I miss?

Comment: It is about the context. Believe or not.. $stateParams act as a standard service (or const as I remember)... That's why we can ask for them via IoC. But before we are in **our current state**... they could contain params from previous state *(could be empty)*. That's why we should use function inside of resolve - because: it provides access to so called **locals** - just created **`$stateParams`** of currently building state. That's the cool feature of the UI-Router

Comment: Thanks, I think I eventually figure a little bit. I'll learn more about ui-router.

Comment: Good luck sir, the UI-Router is relly awesome tool ;) good luck